# Got an error about RayCast when getting the mouse position

Tags: unity-game-engine

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
DragBlock.Update () (at Assets/Script/DragBlock.cs:13)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DragBlock : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isBeingHeld = false;
    private Vector3 startPos;
    private Transform heldObject;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.transform.CompareTag("Blocks"))
                {
                    isBeingHeld = true;
                    startPos = hit.transform.position;
                    heldObject = hit.transform;
                }
            }
        }

        if (isBeingHeld)
        {
            Vector3 currentMousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            currentMousePos.z = heldObject.position.z;
            heldObject.position = currentMousePos;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            isBeingHeld = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the group of the object tried to check the position and so on in this code it should check the position of the mouse and drag the object with the Blocks tag

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. You should look into [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) This would help you know for sure which variable it is. 
Like the answer says it is likely your camera.

Answer (score 1):

If line 13 is this one...

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
```

... then the only part of the code that could realistically be null is the `Camera.main` property. `Camera.main` is returned by Unity when Unity looks for, and finds, a Camera in your scene that's tagged "MainCamera".

I suggest that you might have removed or changed that tag of the Camera, or a parent of the camera, and now Unity can't find an appropriate camera.

This is echoed in the online documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html